# Redirect All Images Under A Selected Path With Query Statement Intact

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the folllowing .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^css/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^flash/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^images/user-images/(.*)$ /index.php?image=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^js/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^swf/.*$ - [PT]
```

I need to adjust one of the lines to accept and maintain the query variables

```
RewriteRule ^images/user-images/(.*)$ /index.php?image=$1 [QSA]
```

The example url this is for looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/images/user-images/Montreal/private/2012_08_10/YzAbCdE.jpg?lang=fr
```

The lang variables always get's stripped how do I still get the above url to work and redirect to http://domain.com/images/user-images/Montreal/private/2012_08_10/YzAbCdE.jpg without losing the lang=fr

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want

```
http://domain.com/images/user-images/path/YzAbCdE.jpg?lang=fr
```

to be mapped to

```
/index.php?image=path%2FYzAbCdE.jpg&lang=fr
```

This would be exaclty what your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^images/user-images/(.*)$ /index.php?image=$1 [QSA]
```

should do. Especially the [QSA] should preserve the lang-parameter, if you want to have the lang-parameter stripped, you'll need [QSD] instead of [QSA].

If that doesn't work, it's maybe because your apache server is too old and doesn't know QSA.

Howevery, you could try to replace the above rewrite rule by:

```
RewriteRule ^images/user-images/([^?]*)$ /index.php?image=$1
RewriteRule ^images/user-images/([^?]*)?(.*)$ /index.php?image=$1&$2
```

Comment: You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var in a `RewriteCond`. Either way, the OP's rules work fine for me as they are.